# calcular raíz cuadrada de 2 con precisión en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Muy buenas a todos

soy nuevo en Python y haciendo un programa me entrampe con los resultados que distan mucho si los hago con una calculadora

**PRIMERO**

ante esta dificultad, entendí que debo importar las librerías de DECIMAL por lo que escribí esta linea de comandos

```
 >import math

 >from decimal import Decimal
```

**SEGUNDO**

con el fin de obtener una precisión de 60 digitos, opte por poner el comando

```
getcontext().prec = 60
```

y me percate que solo funciona hasta 54 digitos

**TERCERO**

motivo por el cual use el comando

```
myothercontext = Context(prec=60, rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
setcontext(myothercontext)
```

**Mi PROGRAMA:**

básicamente quiero hallar la raíz cuadrada de una raíz cuadrada de una raíz cuadra según se ingrese el valor de recurrencia

```
a = Decimal(0)
valorN = 0
i=3

while i <= valorN:
  x = (Decimal(math.sqrt(Decimal(2+a))))
  a = Decimal(math.sqrt(2+a))
  i = i + 1

print(x)
```

cuando inicio con valorN =3, el resultado debería ser la raiz cuadrada de 2 y obtengo un valor
de

1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125

sin embargo el valor exacto es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan, los valores exactos son hasta el digito 1.414213562373095 ... luego todos los demás son diferentes

Mis preguntas
1 porque sucede esto?
2 como puedo solucionarlo?

Apreciare mucho su gentil respuesta

Comment: A qué te refieres con que los resultados "distan mucho" de los que obtienes con una calculadora? Me extraña bastante, ya que tanto las calculadoras como python (como cualquier otro lenguaje hoy día) usan el mismo estándar para la representación de datos de punto flotante (IEEE-754) y tienen por tanto la misma precisión. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de algo que te sale con la calculadora muy diferente de lo que te sale con python?

Comment: Algo debes haber modificado en tu código, porque si la `i = 3` y `valorN = 0` el `while` no se va a ejecutar.

Answer (score 1):

Como el método `math.sqrt()` es de otro módulo independiente, es posible que esté calculando sin usar precisión avanzada. Por suerte, el [módulo decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) tiene un método integrado para calcular la raíz cuadrada con la precisión dada.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 65
>>> decimal.Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797380')
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero esta bien hasta que el valor n es mayor a 28. Que podría hacer para arreglarlo

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, no se entiende claramente qué es lo que quieres hacer. ¿Obtener la raiz de 2 con precisión arbitraria? ¿Implementar tu propia función para cálculo de raices? ¿Calcular raices de raices de raices.... hasta cualquier nivel de profundidad y siempre con precisión arbitraria?

Lo segundo, me temo que algunos de estos objetivos son imposibles. Las raices que no salen exactas, como bien sabes, son irracionales. Esto quiere decir que el número de decimales es infinito. Obviamente no vas a poder encontrar un resultado "exacto" y en algún momento habrá que truncar los decimales y perder el resto.

Dicho esto, vamos con algo de teoria

### El tipo float

El tipo float de python equivale al tipo double de otros lenguajes. Es un formato estandarizado utilizado por todos los computadores y calculadoras. Utiliza 64 bits para guardar un número real. Ya puedes imaginarte que con 64 bits no hay para infinitos decimales. De hecho, de esos 64 bits sólo 52 se usan para guardar la parte decimal (en binario), siendo otros 11 para la parte exponente, y 1 para el signo.

En el caso particular de raiz de 2, que es 1.4142135... o en binario sería 1.011010100000100111100110011... se almacenarían solo los primeros 52 bits que van tras la coma. La precisión por tanto es de 2<sup>-52</sup> que viene a ser del orden de 10<sup>-16</sup> lo que significa que al mostrarlo en base 10 sólo tendrías correctos los primeros 16 decimales, aproximadamente.

Además de las limitaciones de espacio del formato `float`, aparecen efectos secundarios extraños debido a que el número debe ser convertido a binario antes de ser almacenado. El problema es que números de aspecto "inocente" en base 10, como por ejemplo 0.2, al ser escritos en binario producen una cantidad infinita de decimales (en particular, 0.2 en binario sería 0.0011001100110011... que si lo observas bien es periódico puro).

Esto no es tan extraño como pueda parecer a primera vista. En base 10 un número racional como 1/3 también produce infinitos decimales (0.333333...) mientras que en otras bases podría no ser así (en base 3 sería simplemente 0.1).

El caso es que eso causa también que números "normales" como por ejemplo precios en euros tales como 15,20€ al pasarlos a binario ocupen infinitos decimales, y por tanto en un `float` no quepan y acaben siendo truncados provocando errores de redondeo.

### El tipo Decimal

El tipo `decimal.Decimal` implementa los números no enteros de otra forma, que se basa en la base 10 en lugar de la base 2, con el objetivo de que casos como los 15,20€ sean representables de forma exacta y no den lugar a los errores de redondeo de los `float`.

Esto los hace atractivos para operaciones bancarias en las que es frecuente operar con un número finito de decimales, pero se quiere precisión total y no errores de redondeo. Sin embargo no es muy útil para el caso de los números irracionales como raiz de 2, ya que estos tienen infinitos decimales en cualquier base que elijas, y por tanto van a tener siempre errores de redondeo.

La principal ventaja de los `Decimal` es que al menos te permiten especificar cuántos decimales quieres mantener. El espacio que ocupa un `Decimal` no está prefijado a 64 bits como en los `float`, sino que se reserva más espacio según la precisión con que quieras trabajar. Pero esa precisión va a tener siempre un límite (aunque lo eliges tú).

### Tu código

En tu código aparece la siguiente instrucción:

```
x = (Decimal(math.sqrt(Decimal(2+a))))
```

Esa instrucción no tiene mucho sentido, pues lo que hace es:

- Cuando `a` vale 0, `Decimal(2+a)` será `Decimal(2)`. Eso convierte el 2 (que sería un entero) al formato `Decimal()` y por tanto lo deja como `2.00000..00` con un número finito de decimales, digamos 60
- Seguidamente le pasa ese dato a `math.sqrt()`. Ya que esta función sólo trabaja con `float`, lo primero que hace es volver a convertir el 2.000....0 en un flotante, lo  que ya podría introducir un error de redondeo si hubiera habido decimales. En este caso no los hay y el 2 queda correctamente representado. Seguidamente calcula su raiz cuadrada y ya aparecen aqui los problemas, ya que la raiz cuadrada de 2 en el formato `float` está limitada a 52 bits de la parte fracción. O sea, se pierde precisión a partir del dígito 16 al pasarlo a base 10.
- El resultado de esa raiz se convierte de nuevo a `Decimal()`. Pero ya es demasiado tarde porque ese resultado ya estaba "mal" a partir del dígito 16. Los 60 digitos que estás almacenando en `x` son sólo correctos hasta el 16.

#### La solución de @aeportugal

Como @aeportugal ha indicado, sería más correcto utilizar el método `.sqrt()` de la clase `Decimal` ya que esa trabajará directamente con el dato decimal sin las conversiones intermedias a `float` que causaban la pérdida de precisión.

Y de hecho podemos verificar que la respuesta en este caso es correcta:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 60
>>> decimal.Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317668')
```

El resultado mostrado coincide correctamente hasta el último dígito con la solución que produce [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29+with+60+digits) cuando le preguntas cuánto vale "`sqrt(2) with 60 digits`", siendo su respuesta:

```
1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317668
```

### El resto de tus cuestiones

Entonces. Tenemos una forma de calcular sqrt(2) exacto hasta el decimal 60. ¿Para qué querías esto exactamente?

Parece que quieres computar la relación de recurrencia:

```
x_nuevo = sqrt(2+x_previo)
```

lo cual se haría con un bucle como el siguiente:

```
>>> a = decimal.Decimal(0)
>>> for i in range(N):
...   x = (a+2).sqrt()
...   a = x
```

dices que para N hasta 28 funciona, pero luego no. Lo he probado con N=30 y me ha salido:

```
x: Decimal('1.99999999999999999785987069335328430453055355679597492519638')
```

¿Cómo sabes si ese es o no es el resultado correcto? ¿Contra qué lo has comparado? Yo no he sido capaz a encontrar el resultado con Wolfram Alpha. Dudo mucho que una calculadora común te de un resultado mejor...

Comment: En Wolfram Alpha:`RecurrenceTable[{g[1 + n] == Sqrt[2 + g[n]], g[0] == 0}, g, {n,30, 30}, WorkingPrecision->60]`. Resultado el mismo: `1.99999999999999999785987069335328430453055355679597492519638`

Comment: Hola, agradezco tu respuesta que me permite entender un poco mas el Python

El caso es que me encuentro haciendo un programa para determinar el valor de PI con la mayor cantidad de decimales posibles, para lo cual uso un sistema de recurrencias de raíces cuadradas

el bucle que uso es el 

while i <= valorN:
    x1 = decimal.Decimal(2+a).sqrt()
    x   = decimal.Decimal(2-x1).sqrt()
    y   = pow(2,i-1)
    pi  = x*y
    a = decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)+a).sqrt()
    i = i + 1

Comment: el bucle que uso es el 

while i <= valorN:
    x1 = decimal.Decimal(2+a).sqrt()
    x   = decimal.Decimal(2-x1).sqrt()
    y   = pow(2,i-1)
    pi  = x*y
    a = decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)+a).sqrt()
    i = i + 1

el problema que se me presento, es que cuando el valorN es mayor a 28, el valor de los decimales de PI se distorsionan y lo se por que lo comparo con Decimal(math.pi)

Comment: @Marcus. Esto que has planteado se conoce por aqui como "problema XY". Tenías un problema X (computar aproximaciones de pi), pero preguntaste por un problema Y diferente (computar raiz de dos). La causa de este tipo de problemas XY es que tú creías que el problema por el que preguntabas (Y) era la causa de tu verdadero problema (X) pero resulta que no. La raiz cuadrada se está computando con precisión. Incluso los dígitos de pi se están aproximando correctamente, sólo que no al ritmo que tú creías.

Comment: @Marcus Te sugiero que crees una nueva pregunta y en ella pongas el código del anterior comentario (para que de paso se pueda leer bien, que en los comentarios no se lee nada). Pregunta entonces por qué los dígitos de pi se te "distorsionan" para N>28. Puedo darte entonces una respuesta, pero no quisiera complicar más esta otra que ya bastante larga es, y además respondía correctamente a tu prgunta original (problema Y, computar raíz de 2)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: al inicio de mi pregunta expuse que "haciendo un programa", pues creía que el calculo de la raíz cuadrada era la causa de mis problemas, con tu ayuda pude arreglar el tema de la raíz, pero me lastimosamente no soluciono mi problema

seguiré tu sugerencia y abriré otro caso por los dígitos distorsionados de pi en un programa en Python

Comment: @abulafia adjunto el nuevo caso

[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438389/por-qué-los-dígitos-de-pi-se-distorsionan-para-n28-cuando-programo-en-pyth)