# ¿Por qué los dígitos de π se "distorsionan" para n > 28 en Python 3.9?

Tags: python

Estoy escribiendo un programa en Python para calcular el número π con la mayor cantidad de decimales posibles. Mi primera dificultad fue que usaba variables `float` que me restringían el número de decimales.

Gracias a las sugerencias del foro, cambié a `decimal`.

El caso es que mejoró la aproximación de decimales pero solo hasta el decimal número 16, cómo se puede ver como sigue:

**π con mi programa**

`3.1415926535897931` `667462219700150778696165489637681660703093062077`

**π con valor de decimal (math.pi)**

`3.1415926535897931` `15997963468544185161590576171875`

A continuación dejo el código fuente de mi primer programa:

```py
import math
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 65
a = Decimal(0)
valorN = 0
i = 3
pi = Decimal(0)
pi2 = Decimal(math.pi)

valorN = int(input('Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: '))
a = decimal.Decimal(0)

while i <= valorN:
    x1= decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)+a).sqrt()
    x = decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)-x1).sqrt()
    y = decimal.Decimal(pow(2,i-1))
    pi = x*y
    a = decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)+a).sqrt()
    i = i + 1 

print('El valor de pi es ')
print(pi)

# este es el valor real #
print (pi2)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

Tu supuesto "valor exacto de pi" contra el que te comparabas no era exacto. Sólo lo era hasta el decimal 15. De hecho, **el valor de pi que computaba tu bucle *era más correcto*** (y por eso se apartaba del valor de `math.pi` a partir del decimal 15).

De todas formas, el algoritmo que usas para computar pi tiene serios problemas de estabilidad a partir de un punto. [Ver **ampliación** final para una posible solución]

### Comprender Decimal

Lo primero, el tipo `Decimal()` no es una fórmula milagrosa. Cuando conviertes un `float` a `Decimal` no vas a obtener instantáneamente más precisión de la que tenía el `float` de entrada. Por ejemplo, si tú le pides representar con 51 decimales la cantidad 3.14, no vas a obtener más decimales de pi, es más, ni siquiera vas a obtener 3.1400000...00000 (49 ceros) sino

```
>>> print(decimal.Decimal(3.14))
3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875
```

Como ves, a partir de un punto aparecen decimales "raros". Esos decimales *ya estaban ahí* en el número 3.14 porque su representación en binario tiene infinitos decimales, y ya que el guardarlo en `float` eso se trunca, se está cometiendo un error. Dicho de otro modo, cuando haces `a = 3.14` (tipo float), en realidad el número que queda almacenado en `a` es una *aproximación* de 3.14 (y en concreto, la aproximación mostrada más arriba).

Para evitar estos errores de redondeo no deberías pasarle un `float` al constructor de `Decimal()`, sino una cadena. Si hacemos `Decimal("3.14")`, entonces sí, el valor almacenado será exacto:

```
>>> print(decimal.Decimal("3.14"))
3.14
# Almacena en realidad
# 3.140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Aunque a la hora de imprimirlo no muestra los ceros no significativos, en realidad están correctamente almacenados dentro de la representación Decimal.

Digo todo esto porque comienzas con:

```
pi2 = Decimal(math.pi)
```

y consideras que esta variable es "el valor exacto de pi", pero no lo es ya que ha sido generado a partir de `math.pi` que es una aproximación válida sólo hasta el decimal 15, debido a que es un número de punto flotante que tiene errores inherentes como ya [fue explicado aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436597/calcular-ra%C3%ADz-cuadrada-de-2-con-precisi%C3%B3n-en-python)

Compara el valor de `pi2` con un valor más exacto generado por [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+with+65+decimals) hasta el decimal 65:

```
Exacto con 65 cifras: 3.141592653589793 23846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459231
    Decimal(math.pi): 3.141592653589793 115997963468544185161590576171875
```

### Algunos detalles adicionales sobre tu programa

En tu programa tienes varios `decimal.Decimal()` que podrían eliminarse.

Por ejemplo sobra aqui:

```
x1 = decimal.Decimal(Decimal(2)+a).sqrt()
```

que puede abreviarse a:

```
x1 = (a+2).sqrt()
```

puesto que `a` ya era de tipo `Decimal`, por lo que `a+2` será también `Decimal` (python convertirá `2` en `Decimal`, de forma exacta por tratarse de un entero, y hará la suma). Ya que el resultado es un `Decimal()` y aplicamos sobre él el método `.sqrt()` de los `Decimal()`, el resultado de esa raiz será a su vez otro `Decimal()` que podemos asignar a `x1` directamente, sin necesidad de convertirlo de nuevo en `Decimal()`

### Ejecutando tu programa corregido

Vamos a ejecutar una versión simplificada (quitando lo `decimal.Decimal()` superfluos) en la que nos comparamos con el valor "verdadero" de pi, al menos hasta la cifra 65, que es el que hemos obtenido de Wolfram Alpha

Este es el programa:

```
# @title pi
import math
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 65

a = Decimal(0)
valorN = 0
i = 3

pi = Decimal(0)
pi2 = Decimal("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459231")

valorN = int(input('Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: '))
a = Decimal(0)

while i <= valorN:
    x1= (2+a).sqrt()
    x = (2-x1).sqrt()
    y = Decimal(pow(2,i-1))
    pi = x*y
    a = (2+a).sqrt()
    i = i + 1 

print('El valor de pi es ')
print(pi)
# este es el valor real #
print (pi2)
```

Al ejecutarlo para N=28 obtenemos resultados correctos hasta el decimal 15

```
Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: 28
El valor de pi es 
3.141592653589793 1667462219700150778696165489637681660703093062077
3.141592653589793 23846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459231
```

Pero ¿qué esperabas? En 28 iteraciones del algoritmo esa es la precisión que se ha logrado. Si quieres más precisión, podemos seguir iterando. Probemos por ejemplo 35 iteraciones:

```
Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: 35
El valor de pi es 
3.1415926535897932384 582661602928534441638628573935649839361286949
3.1415926535897932384 6264338327950288419716939937510582097494459231
```

Como vemos ha mejorado la precisión que ahora tenemos 19 decimales correctos (que ya es más de lo que podríamos tener en un `float`).

Ocurre que N iteraciones no te da N decimales correctos. El algoritmo no converge tan rápido. Para lograr 19 decimales debes iterar 35 veces. Pero a partir de un punto seguir iterando ya no mejora el resultado. De hecho lo empeora!

### El problema con este enfoque

Este no es un buen mecanismo para encontrar decimales de pi, pues es inestable. A medida que iteras, `x1` es cada vez más próximo a 2, por lo que `2-x1` es cada vez más próximo a cero, y por tanto `x` también.

De hecho llega un momento en que los 65 decimales no son suficientes para guardar `x` (que sería inferior a 10^-65) y su valor se trunca a cero. A partir de ese punto todo falla, pues si `x` es cero, también lo será `x**y` y por tanto de pronto tu aproximación de pi se convierte en cero.

Esto pasa relativamente pronto (para n=110). Pero bastante antes de que eso ocurra, aparecen errores importantes en el cómputo de `x**y`, ya que `x` tomará valores muy pequeños, mientras que `y` va tomando valores muy grandes (potencias de 2). En los valores pequeños de `x` hay un error debido a que estamos truncándolo en su decimal 65, y ese error se ve amplificado al elevarlo a `y`. El resultado es que antes de que se produzca la "catástrofe" que hace que `pi` pase a valer cero, ya las aproximaciones previas eran cada vez peores en vez de ser cada vez mejores.

Por ejemplo, para `n=105` la aproximación de `pi` que salía era:

```
Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: 105
El valor de pi es 
3.14 21373846360117824379164873499126756724026658776749425705467686
3.14 15926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923
```

¡Toma! ¡Está mal ya a partir del tercer decimal!

Parece entonces que a medida que aumentamos N nos vamos aproximando a pi, pero sólo hasta un punto a partir del cual nos alejamos de nuevo debido a los errores causados porque `x` es muy muy pequeño y no cabe en 65 decimales, hasta que finalmente el error es ya catastrófico pues nuestro pi vale cero.

### Curiosidades finales

Como curiosidad he hecho una gráfica de cuál es el error absoluto cometido (diferencia entre la aproximación de pi y su valor "verdadero") a medida que aumentamos N (iteraciones del bucle):

[image: Error]

He usado escala logarítmica en el eje Y. Vemos como hasta N aproximadamente igual a 53 la cosa iba bien. El error se iba reduciendo exponencialmente, pero a partir de ahi la cosa se torció. Los errores de redondeo debido a la inestabilidad `x**y` hicieron que el error fuera creciendo de nuevo (de forma irregular, un tanto caótica), hasta llegar a un error igual a 3.1415... cuando `pi` pasa a valer 0 (y a partir de ese punto el error ya se queda en 3.1415.. porque toda iteración siguiente del bucle produce `pi = 0`.

Para N=53 se produce la mejor aproximación de todas, que es la siguiente:

```
Ingrese el valor de n que sea mayor a 2 y menor a infinito: 53
El valor de pi es 
3.141592653589793238462643383279 4390490856382359047953080772238233
3.141592653589793238462643383279 5028841971693993751058209749445923
```

correcta hasta el decimal 30.

He pintado otra gráfica que muestra cuántos dígitos correctos tiene la aproximación a medida que aumentas `valorN`. Es la siguiente:

[image: Digitos correctos]

Donde se ve de nuevo que el máximo se alcanza para N alrededor de 55 y también que hasta ese momento la progresión no es lineal. En ocasiones pasar de N a N+1 aumenta el número de dígitos correctos en 1, otras veces no lo aumenta. Y a partir de 55 el número de dígitos correctos disminuye, también "a saltos".

Parece por tanto que con una precisión de 65 llegas correctamente hasta el decimal 30. Ampliando la precisión podrías obtener más decimales correctos.

## Ampliación

Aparentemente, según algunas pruebas que he estado haciendo, para obtener N dígitos correctos, tienes que trabajar con una precisión de al menos 2*(N+3) (es un heurístico para el que no tengo justificación). Así, para obtener correctamente 65 dígitos deberías trabajar con una precisión de
136.

En lugar de pedirle al usuario el número de iteraciones a realizar, podemos detectar automáticamente cuándo parar, y será cuando el valor que nos sale de `pi` sea igual al de la iteración anterior (a partir de ese punto la aproximación comenzaría a empeorar).

Este sería por tanto el código:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

valorN = int(input('Ingrese el valor de dígitos deseado: '))

# Trabajar con la precisión adecuada
decimal.getcontext().prec = 2*(valorN+3)

a = Decimal(0)
i = 3
pi = Decimal(0)
a = Decimal(0)

while True:
    piold = pi
    x1= (2+a).sqrt()
    x = (2-x1).sqrt()
    y = Decimal(pow(2,i-1))
    pi = x*y
    if piold==pi:
      break
    a = (2+a).sqrt()
    i = i + 1 

print(f"Detenido tras {i} iteraciones")
print('El valor aproximado de pi es ')
print(pi)
# este es el valor real con 65 digitos #
print("3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923")
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

```
Ingrese el valor de dígitos deseado: 65
Detenido tras 116 iteraciones
El valor aproximado de pi es 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307844062894732236752971209989019846026985971418316643805175816308465281
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923
```

Naturalmente el resto de decimales que salen a partir de la posición 65 estarían mal. Podríamos truncar el resultado con:

```
print(str(pi)[:valorN+1])
```

Comment: Estupenda respuesta. Al final la precisión un problema de representación. Los humanos queremos una representación decimal, las computadoras prefieren el binario (float point), mientras que las matemáticas parece que prefieren la codificación hexadecimal para el número pi (fórmula de Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe). Lástima que tengamos `float.fromhex` y no `decimal.fromhex` (En Julia sí que hay algo).

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente obtenía 0 para el valor de pi y creía que el problema era de otro tipo. Entonces se podría decir que con Python solo podemos hallar un numero ilimitado de decimales de pi.

Comment: @ChemaCortes ¿Eso significa que con Julia podemos obtener mayor precisión en la cantidad de decimales de pi, que Python? ¿Por que?

Comment: @Marcus El problema no es de Python ni de Julia. El problema es que el algoritmo que has elegido para computar pi no es precisamente el mejor. Acabo de escribir [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/440372/7123) sobre este tema, en la que me he respondido a mi mismo con un par de algoritmos alternativos, mucho más eficientes que el que intentas usar

Comment: @Marcus Lo que decía es que en Julia se puede representar números de coma flotante codificados en hexadecimal y precisión arbitraria. Para los cálculos integra la librería MPFR, algo que también puede usar Python para hacer lo mismo o mejor. Por ejemplo, con [sage](https://sagemath.org/) es posible calcular π con precisión arbitraria: `RealField(1000000).pi()` (un millón de bits de mantisa). De todas formas, la representación binaria de un número real siempre será aproximada, por lo que los errores se acumulan con cada operación. Mira la estupenda respuesta de @abulafia.